# Java - Instance able to access static method

Tags: java, static, instance-variables, nested-class

I just started with Java again, was looking into the `Nested Classes` topic, and was trying out some stuff, when suddenly, this happened:

```
class Encloser
{
  static int i;

  static void m1()
  {
    System.out.println(i);
  }

  static void m2()
  {
    Enclosee.accessEncloser();
  }

  static class Enclosee
  {
    static void accessEncloser()
    {
      i = 1;
      m1();
    }

    static void accessEncloserNew()
    {
      m2();
    }
  }
}

class EncloserTest
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Encloser ee = new Encloser();
    Encloser.Enclosee e = new Encloser.Enclosee();
    ee.m1();
    ee.m2();
    e.accessEncloser();
    e.accessEncloserNew();Encloser.m1();
    Encloser.m2();
    Encloser.m1();
    Encloser.Enclosee.accessEncloserNew();
    Encloser.Enclosee.accessEncloser();
  }

}
```

Running the above code doesn't give any error/exception. It just runs. The confusion here is, how are instances able to call the `Static Methods` here? Aren't `Static Methods` like the `Class Methods` in `Ruby`?

Any explaination would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what language allows:

```
ee.m1();
```

but you should rather write:

```
Encloser.m1();
```

you compiler should issue warning like below, to inform you of that:

> source_file.java:37: warning: [static] static method should be
>   qualified by type name, Encloser, instead of by an expression
>       ee.m1();

Comment: Thanks for the prompt repliy @marcin_j :) But just FYI, i didn't get any warnings :|

Comment: Maybe it depends on ide / java compiler / used parameters, I pasted your code into http://rextester.com/runcode.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods can be accessed (but should not be, as a good programming practice) by objects too, because at compile time, **these variable types are resolved into class names**.

Comment: It's slightly better, but OP is confused about "accessing by objects", which doesn't at all happen, however your answer reads otherwise. No objects at all are involved here, and even variables are optional. `((Encloser)null).m1()` brings this out most poignantly.

Answer (score 2):

In compile time instance variables are replaced with class names if they are calling static methods.

`ee.m1();` is interpreted as `Enclosee.m1();`